# how to loop the my codes depends on array length

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It is my pdf viewer and in this pdf, each row contains 3 items based on 'detailData'.
I just want to loop the code below based on detailData length.

just completed first rows but I'm stuck with next steps.
Here is my incompleted react codes and what I'm trying to do.

[For Example]

1. if detailData length is 24. then each row display 3 items of detailData
   and total row number going to be 8.
2. if detailData length is 7. then each row also display 3 items of detailData
   and total row number going to be 3.

Please guide me to solve this issue.

```
...
...
...

const drawDetails = (detailData: any) => {
  let pdfData: any = [];


 /////[TODO]v//////
 //Want to loop depends on 'detailData.length' 
 // each row has to be shown 3 columns
 // e.g --> if detailData.length is 24
 // 1 row contains 3 items and total row going to be 8
 ///////////

  detailData &&
    pdfData.push(
        //the row
      <View style={styles.row}>
         //display first 3 items of detailData
        {detailData?.slice(0, 3).map((item: any) => (
       //1 column for 1 item
          <View style={styles.column}>
            <View style={styles.textWrap}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Post no</Text>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{item?.box_number}</Text>
            </View>

            <Image
              source={`data:image/png;base64, ${item?.barcode}`}
              style={styles.imgSource}
            />
            <Text style={styles.boxText}>{item?.box_barcode}</Text>
            <View style={styles.infoWrap}>
              <View style={styles.subRow}>
                <Text style={styles.subText}>
                  storeName: :{'\t\t\t\t\t' + item?.store_name}
                </Text>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.subRowTop}>
                <Text style={styles.subText}>
                  finalDate :
                  {'\t\t' + item?.receipt_date + `~` + item?.finaldate}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
//end of the column
          </View>
        ))}
//end of 1 row
      </View>,
    );

  return pdfData;
};

// Create Document Component
const PdfDetail = (detailData: any) => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        {detailData && drawDetails(detailData)}
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

export default PdfDetail;
```

Comment: Does this [pagination tutorial](https://medium.com/how-to-react/create-pagination-in-reactjs-e4326c1b9855) help you?

Comment: Thank you Yaman it gave me some idea but still I am stuck with above code.